# Onde usar o \n no printf?

Tags: c, printf

Olá, a minha dúvida é em relação a onde colocar o `\n`.

Eu vejo várias situações em que o `\n` é utilizado no final do `printf`:

```
int x = 2, y = 3;

printf("X = %d\n",x);

printf("Y = %d",y);
```

Mas também, vejo ele sendo utilizado no começo:

```
int x = 2, y = 3;

printf("X = %d",x);

printf("\nY = %d",y);
```

Eu gostaria de saber se:

Existe diferença em colocar o `\n` no começo ou no final do `printf`?

Algum desses métodos é mais recomendável?

E se eu quiser pular duas ou mais linhas, eu coloco vários `\n` seguidos ou tem algum outro jeito?

Desde já, muito obrigado.

Comment: "*Existe diferença em colocar o \n no começo ou no final do printf?*" - sim, se colocar no começo, primeiro ele pula a linha e depois escreve o resto, e se colocar no final, primeiro ele escreve tudo e no final pula a linha. No seu exemplo específico não faz diferença, claro, e não existe essa de "recomendável", tudo depende do que você precisa. Coloque `\n` quando vc quiser que pule a linha, não importa se está no "início" ou no "fim". Só pra constar, no seu caso daria para fazer em um único comando: `printf("X = %d\nY = %d", x, y);`

Comment: Mas e se eu quiser pular várias linhas? Eu coloco vários ```\n```?

Comment: O caractere '\n' passa para a linha seguinte. Se utilizar 2 consecutivos o resultado será uma linha em branco. Se 3 consecutivos então 2 linhas em branco e assim sucessivamente. Nada que um simples teste não esclarecesse.

Comment: Sim, pra pular várias linhas, coloque vários `\n`. Vc tentou? :-) **Se** "várias" forem realmente muitas, aí talvez valha a pena fazer um *loop*: `for (int i = 0; i < qtdLinhas; i++) printf("\n")` - mas se for só 2 ou 3, nem compensa fazer isso, coloque `\n\n` mesmo...

Comment: Sim, eu fiz o teste e sabia que funcionava, só queria saber se existia alguma função, ou algo assim, para pular várias linhas sem ter que digitar várias vezes ```\n``` ou ter que utilizar um loop, mas obrigado pelo esclarecimento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `\n` significa quebra de linha, quando você coloca ele na sua `string` significa que você quer pular uma linha, pois para o `compilador` se você pular várias linhas ou nenhuma linha para ele é a mesma coisa, com `\n` você pode dizer para ele que teve uma quebra de linha, seria semelhante a *tag* `<br>` no `html`.

Ex de código `C++`:

```
...
cout << "Boa tarde" << endl;
cout << "Tudo bem?" << endl;
...
Saída:

Boa tarde
Tudo bem?
```

```
...
cout << "Boa tarde\n" << endl;
cout << "Tudo bem?" << endl;

Saída:

Boa tarde

Tudo bem?
...
```

Ouve apenas uma quebra de linha, logo não faz diferença para o código onde está o `\n`(nem é obrigatorio usar), ele é apenas útil para melhor visualização das saídas.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela atenção e disposição em responder a minha pergunta.